# SharePoint Expiration Policy does not fire ItemDeleting Event Receiver

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We have attached an ItemDeleting event receiver to a list that requires certain maintenance to be performed in other lists whenever an item is deleted.  It works fine when an item is manually deleted by a user.  However, if an item is deleted as a result of the Information Management Policy we have defined to delete expired items, the ItemDeleting handler is not executing.  Is this standard MOSS behavior?  If so, are there any suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I would run a custom workflow using the policy, there you can define your own logic, which is what you probably try to achieve

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vladi.  I can see how I can perform much of the required logic in a custom workflow, but how could I then proceed to delete the expired item?  I didn't think you could delete the list item that triggers a workflow from the workflow itself, or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm sure you could do it, maybe in code, under a different user, if necessary, but i need to check it